# Do the Crimean Jews have stories about the Khazars?

Tags: agada-stories-legends, kuzari

It seems reasonable to say that the (Jewish) Khazars fleeing the destruction of their state by the Rus' could have joined the Crimean Jews. Do the Crimean Jews themselves have any info on the Khazars? Be it in writing or folk legend.